# Possible combinations of the sum of two elements of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a length of four (e.g., nums = [4, 1, 8, 7]). I want to find different possible combinations of the sum of two elements of this list. I wrote the following codes and it works correctly. How can I make it simpler? Please note that we can not use any packages.

```
my_sum = [i + j for i , j in zip(nums, nums[1:])] + [i + j for i , j in zip(nums, nums[2:])]  + [i + j for i , j in zip(nums, nums[3:])]
```

Comment: Why not use loops? Does it have to a list comprehension?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing a solution which also takes care of duplicates. You can use set and a list comprehension, without using any package. Loop over the list and take sum of all the different elements. The condition `i1!=i2` ensures that you add different elements

**Case 1**

```
nums = [4, 1, 8, 7]
my_sum = list(set([n1+n2 for i1, n1 in enumerate(nums) for i2, n2 in enumerate(nums) if i1!=i2] ))
# [5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15]
```

**Case 2**

```
nums = [1, 1, 8, 7]
my_sum = list(set([n1+n2 for i1, n1 in enumerate(nums) for i2, n2 in enumerate(nums) if i1!=i2] ))
# [8, 9, 2, 15]
```

**Case 3**

```
nums = [4,1,4]
my_sum = list(set([n1+n2 for i1, n1 in enumerate(nums) for i2, n2 in enumerate(nums) if i1!=i2] ))
# [8, 5]
```

Comment: This does not work if our list is nums = [1, 1, 8, 7]. I mean if we the same number in our list.